# Matlab legend color incorrect, in a loop of variable size, reading in legend names

Tags: matlab, loops, colors, legend

I feel like I have read through/attempted every online suggestion about this - perhaps missing the obvious! In Matlab R2013a I am plotting multiple lines from a loop (the number of lines read in each time is variable) and then adding a legend, where the series names are read in from a list. The line colors on the legend do not match the line colors on the plot.

I have tried color maps, get & set commands, putting the legend in and outside the loop, creating a separate loop for the legend etc etc... Please help! The relevant section of the code is below:

```
%% getting the data....
for i=1:length(files); % for each file in the folder
  FileName = files(i,1).name; % extract the filename
  calfile = files(i,1).name; % lists all filenames for metadata
  a = length(calfile);
  fn(i,1:a) = calfile;
  fid_data(i) = fopen(files(i,1).name,'r'); % open that file
  data = csvread(FileName,0,1,[0 1 15 30]); % 
  diam(i,:) = data(9,:); % puts each channel center diameter into array
  diamerr(i,:) = data(10,:); % channel centre error
end

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];

%% Plotting data
h = (figure('name','campaign summary','numbertitle','off'));
set(gca, 'box','on')

for r = 1:i
   plot(x,diam(r,:)); % plots diameters for each flight
   hold all
   errorbar(diam(r,:), diamerr(r,:)); % plots error bars for each flight diameters
end

legend(fn(:,:),'location', 'northwest'); % legend derived from filename list
set(legend,'Interpreter','none'); % stops the underscore from making text subscript
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need both `plot` and `errorbar`.  The `errorbar` function is drawing over the line plotted earlier in the loop with `plot`.  The legend is then applied to these hidden lines as well as the visible ones. Get rid of `plot` and use `errorbar(x, diam(r,:), diamerr(r,:))` instead.

Comment: Fabulous! That worked a treat, thank you very much for your help. Stress levels are now subsiding..... :0)